# Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to work in Visual Studio 2017 but my c++ code is failing to compile. it is giving error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code
>   -1073741701.  Project1    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  423

The program does not contain any complex code. Do I need to download any packages to run the program? I am currently working in Windows 8.1

I first tried in Visual Studio 2019 but it reflected the same error. So I tried in a version lower than this. I, however, have visual studio 10 running perfectly in my system.

```
 #include<iostream>
  int main()
   {
      return 0;
   }
```

//
I expect the code to be compiled.

Comment: Yes this is the minimal code example. Do i need to change the framework version or anything to make it work. I have seen different error codes related to MSB6006 but i cant figure out which will work out. Please provide a solution to this. Thankyou

Comment: `-1073741701` translates to `0xC000007B` which is "application unable to start correctly", this usually means you are missing some dlls, reinstall visual studio

Comment: I tried installing two times. Do i need to select some selective pacakages while downloading??

Comment: yes, If you want compile C++ code, you should choose desktop development with C++

Comment: No.. it didn't work. I installed desktop development . The error remains same.

Comment: Alan is not quite right, 0xC000007B says that it did find the EXE or DLL file but the file content is corrupted and can no longer be recognized as an executable file.  You need to reinstall to fix the damage, after checking the health of the disk drive.

Comment: 0xC000007B seems to correspond to ERROR_INVALID_NAME, which suggests a garbled file or directory name.  This is definitely a local configuration problem.  VS 2017 certainly can compile the given code sample.

Comment: Hello, find the CL.exe in your disk. For example, my IDE is visual studio 2017, the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe. Find it and open it. Yes, the program will report errors. some files are missing. Usually these missing files are .dll files. Then go download the missing files and put them in the path above.